# Codeigniter loading ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Trying to add some ajax functionality within a voting system and it's not working. I'm wanting to send a post request to the database and update the count value. Problem I'm running into is that I can't seem to get the ajax request tow work within the MVC.

I do want to retain the MVC structure.

The jquery code is:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#vote li a" ).each(function( index ) {
        $(this).click(function(){
            $.ajax = ajax(); 
            var id = $(this).attr('data-scenario-id');
            var value = $(this).attr('data-value');

            $.ajax({
              url: "ajax-vote.php",
              cache: false,
              data: { id: id, value: value }
            })
             .done(function( html ) {
                $(this).html( html );
             });

            return false;

        });  
    });
});
```

and the php code currently residing in ajax-vote.php is:

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null;
$value = isset($_GET['value']) ? $_GET['value'] : null;

$query = $this->db->query('SELECT count FROM total_counts WHERE scenario_id = ' . $id . ' AND interaction_id = ' . $value);

$row = $query->row(); 
$count = $row->name;
$count++;

$query = $this->db->query('UPDATE total_counts SET count = ' . $count);
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT count FROM total_counts WHERE scenario_id = ' . $id . ' AND   interaction_id = ' . $value);
$row = $query->row();
$count = $row->name;

switch ($value) {
case 1:
    $text = 'OK '. $count;
    break;
case 2:
    $text = 'NOT OK'. $count;
    break;
case 3:
    $text = 'ABUSE'. $count;
    break;
}

echo '<a href="#" data-scenario-id="'.$id.'" data-value="'.$value.'">'. $text .'</a>';
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is ajax-vote is a controller or a plain file outside your CI setup??

Comment: ajax-vote is a plain file in the root of the app - I would like to include it as the app otherwise I would have to hardcode the functionality and add extra bloat to the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with `codeigniter` than you than you have to give controller path in the url. I am assuming your controller name is ajax-vote.php than your ajax code would be

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#vote li a" ).each(function( index ) {
        $(this).click(function(){
            $.ajax = ajax(); 
            var id = $(this).attr('data-scenario-id');
            var value = $(this).attr('data-value');

            $.ajax({
              url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>ajax-vote",
              cache: false,
              data: { id: id, value: value }
            })
             .done(function( html ) {
                $(this).html( html );
             });

            return false;

        });  
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't reference the ajax-vote.php outside of the application framework and it would break the url structure. when I change the url to include my home controller ie base_url(home/vote) I get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined - Does this mean it's found the functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You must put your code into a controller, not in a simple php file! Then you can pass to javascript the codeigniters site_url path like this:

```
<script> var site_url = '<?php echo site_url()?>';</script>
```

You must do this in your header view.

then later in your ajax call you can use this variable to build the path:

```
        $.ajax({
          url: site_url + "ajaxcontroller/vote",
          cache: false,
          data: { id: id, value: value }
        })
         .done(function( html ) {
            $(this).html( html );
         });
```

now you have php and javascript separated.

Of course you have to do an AjaxController extending CI_Controller, and put your code inside a function called "ajax" (or whatever you want, just make sure to use the same name what you used in the js call)